# Pull database from Genymotion emulator

Tags: android, database, adb, pull, genymotion

I am using Windows7 and want to extract/pull the application database to the local windows machine's folder.

I have searched through internet and found the adb command as below :

> adb shell su 0 cp /data/data/<package.name>/databases/<database.name> /mnt/shared/

I have tried the same by creating shared folder for the Virtual box.

But getting error is like : read-only file system

I have also check that read-only is disabled.

Please I need help.

Screenshots :
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you explain when this error occurs and what is your host's OS?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure for Windows but on Mac you just call

`adb pull /data/data/<package.name>/database/<database.name> <local.file.path>`

Answer (score 0):

As your phone under Genymotion is rooted, you can go in the DDMS of Eclipse.

Then, Click on the tab file explorer.

Then go to folder `/data/data/<your.package.name>/` then pull the file from the path in which you saved your database.

Comment: How can we make phone rooted under Genymotion?